# Tkinter difference between <event> and <<event>>

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I am having difficulty looking for this on the internet - my search skills aren't up the scratch.   I can remember the event names, but I always have to look up what type of angle brackets to use

Some tkinter events are bound with words in <> for example

```
tab4e.bind("<Button-1>",f_x)
```

Others are in <<>>, for example

```
nbook.bind('<<NotebookTabChanged>>', handle_tab_changed)
```

Is there any reason why some bindings are in <> and others in <<>>?

Even though the examples are given in python, I've added TCL, just in case a TCL coder might know the answer.

Comment: The double arrow indicates a custom\virtual event created by the developer

Comment: @Mike67 if you write that up, I'll accept it as the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bindings that have a single set of brackets are built-in events directly supported by the underlying OS. Examples include `<KeyPress>`, `<ButtonPress-1>`, `<Configure>`, and many more. Most of the built-in events are directly tied to actual physical events such as pressing a mouse button or key on the keyboard.

Bindings with double-brackets are called *virtual events*. They do not necessarily represent any sort of physical event, and typically (though not always) are unique to specific widgets. For example, `<<ListboxSelect>>` is only used by the listbox, `<<NotebookTabChanged>>` is only used by the ttk notebook, and so on.

Virtual events can be triggered by a combination of other events using the `event_add` widget method, though they can also be generated by calling `event_generate`.

The tcl/tk man pages includes a [list of predefined virtual events](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/event.htm#M41).

Comment: Virtual events serve two purposes: abstracting away from platform differences for how to do some things (such as how to `<<Copy>>`), and conveying events that don't really correspond to anything from the outside at all (`<<NotebookTabChanged>>` is an example of this).

Answer (score 4):

(Keep @Oakley's answer)

Here is an example of a custom event:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def button_click():
    num = random.randint(1,10)  # data to pass, state must be integer
    root.event_generate("<<myevent>>", when="tail", state=num)  # add event to end of event queue, pass state (optional)

def myhandler(evt):  # handle custom event
    print('custom event handled', evt.state)

root = Tk()

button = Button(root, text="Click Me!", command=button_click)
root.bind("<<myevent>>", myhandler)  # create custom event and set handler

button.pack() 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's _technically_ possible to make your own standard event… but it requires writing a non-trivial amount of C code in the Tk library itself to do the structure definition, event generation, and binding resolution. Very much not for anyone wanting the easy life! Virtual events only allow a predefined set of attributes, but can be defined in script code (and those attributes are the most commonly useful ones).